# ESP32 Select one from multiple Wifi/AP with same Name/SSID

Tags: arduino-esp32

Let's say that there are **multiple** found **access points (AP)** with the **same name (SSID)**. How can I choose to which one to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Behind a SSID there is a BSSID/MAC of the AP.

**First find the BSSID/MAC of the AP from the duplicate SSIDs.**

For example if you are using a route visit its configuration page:

[image]

There are many ways that it can be found.

Then just set it:

```
//C4 : 48 : FA : 41 : 26 : 99
//196  72  250   65   38   153
const uint8_t bssid[6] = {196, 72, 250, 65, 38, 153};
String ssid = "Java4Ever";
String password = "XXX";
WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str(), 0, bssid, true);
```

Note that in my case it is not necessary to set the BSSID, because the ESP32 can receive only in 2.4Ghz thus the other AP is not visible to it.